# jQuery Ajax post to php not printing response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the new way to post data to a php page through ajax without a page refresh but the response is not printing to the console.

Note: I am not yet collecting form data to send until I can actually get the ajax to work.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="process.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
      <span class="error">Email not entered</span><br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pword" name="pword">
      <span class="error">Password not entered</span><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="fname">
      <span class="error">First Name not entered</span><br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname">
      <span class="error">Last Name not entered</span><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){e.preventDefault()});

var request = $.ajax({
    url         : 'process.php',
    method      : 'POST',
    data        : {name: 'Robert'},
    dataType    : 'html'
});

request.done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});

request.fail(function(){
    console.log('fail');
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($GLOBALS);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: So what do you see when you look at the console and the network tab. Do you see the Ajax call go out? Do you realize that it is being called on page load and not when you submit the form?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I see it in the network tab.  I see what you mean and what I did wrong.

Comment: The comment above is correct. Moreover, instead of using input type submit and prevent default, you can use input type button and .on('click', function(..) { // ajax call })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your on submit function is not doing anything. You need to have the ajax call inside of it.

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url         : 'process.php',
            method      : 'POST',
            data        : {name: 'Robert'},
            dataType    : 'html'
        })
        .done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log('fail');
        });
    });

});
```

Also I do not know where you are loading the JS.  But you might want to wrap it in a document ready function to make sure your form exist when it is called.

Lastly there is a very nice plugin for forms that will make this easier for you. JQuery.Form.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/